# What does "Proficient as: Dagger" mean in Mage's Blade enchantment?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, equipment

I'm using Mage's Blade enchantment on a rapier. Does this Mage's Rapier now count as a dagger for powers and feats that need a dagger or what does "Proficient as: Dagger" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Mage's Blade enchantment on a rapier. Does this Mage's Rapier now count as a dagger for powers and feats that need a dagger or what does "Proficient as: Dagger" mean?

No, it does not count as a dagger for powers and feats that need a dagger. You cannot hope to gain the benefits from *Rogue Weapon Talent* while wielding a Mage's Rapier. Likewise, you cannot use a Mage's Rapier with the Sorcerer's *Ensorcelled Blade* power and you cannot use a Mage's Rapier as a Sorcerer implement (like a dagger).

What you can do, is use a Mage's Rapier on characters that would otherwise be non-proficient with Rapiers so long as they are proficient with simple weapons or daggers (meaning, pretty much everybody). In other words, for the use of a weapon enchant, you get the equivalent of a weapon proficiency feat.

To get the most use out of it, I'd suggest placing a Mage's Weapon enchantment on a superior weapon because there are cheaper ways (like backgrounds) to get access to military weapons like rapiers. That's also assuming your character is feat-starved (who isn't?) and you need a weapon upgrade.

Comment: What superior weapon would you suggest? I still need a light blade.

Comment: A rapier is still a good light one-handed blade (even if it is a military melee weapon rather than a superior weapon). I was suggesting there were cheaper ways to get proficiency with a Rapier than using up your weapon enchant. Depending on your character, the Gritty Sargeant background may be cheaper. If you are considering a Hybrid character it is important to note that weapon proficiencies are additive between the two classes (unlike armor proficiencies).

Comment: May I post my complete build here on rpg.stackexchange for some feedback? Don't know if this would be on or off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are talking about a Mage's Weapon (Adventurer's Vault p. 72), it says quite clearly in the description:

> Anyone proficient with simple weapons or the dagger is proficient with this weapon.

Comment: Why should it be of any importance? I'm proficient with a weapon or not, why is the dagger stated explicitly?

That's the only source I foudn about this issue [click](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?319707-Worn-Accessory-Arcane-Implement/page2)

Comment: Because some classes (like the Mage IIRC), are not proficient on all simple weapons, but are proficient with a dagger, so they are still able to be proficient with it. The "simple weapons" is slightly redundant, but I guess they might want to avoid something thinking that they were "only" proficient with simple weapons, and thus couldn't use it effectively.

Comment: But this effect is sufficiently described in the property of the enchantment:

"Anyone proficient with simple weapons or the dagger is proficient with this weapon"

So what is the value of this addition "Proficient as: Dagger", there are other sorces of weapon proficiencies without such an additional item property.

Comment: @BlackEye Because if they hadn't put that in there I guarantee there would be someone on these forums asking why a Mage would use a weapon of a given class when they're not proficient. Some people read too much into things. Some people don't read enough. RPG authors of highly detailed systems tend to assume the latter.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are reading this "Proficient as: Dagger"? I don't see that anywhere in the item description from the compendium.